How to Launch Location Resolution Through Launcher and get Result in Composable Screen not Activity (Location Service GPS On)
I'm working on a Jetpack Compose application, and I need to handle location settings resolution. I want to check whether the device's location settings are enabled (e.g., GPS and high accuracy), and if not, show a resolution dialog to allow the user to enable them.
I don't know how to launch this via laucher.
locationSettingsLauncher.launch(resolvable.resolution) //(need to get result in launcher)

//resolvable.startResolutionForResult(activity, LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST) (it will work but i am not ready to get result in parent activity of compose screen)

val LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST = 245

fun enableLoc(context: Context, locationSettingsLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>) {
    val activity = context.findActivity()
    // Create a LocationRequest object

    val locationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 30 * 1000L)
        .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)
        .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(5 * 1000L)
        .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(100)
        .build()

    // Build LocationSettingsRequest
    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().apply {
        addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
        setAlwaysShow(true)  // Always show the prompt if location is not enabled
    }

    // Check the location settings
    LocationServices
        .getSettingsClient(activity)
        .checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                requestLocationUpdates()
            } else {
                // The task failed, handle the exception
                try {
                    val exception = task.exception
                    if (exception is ResolvableApiException) {
                        // The exception is of type ResolvableApiException, so you need to resolve it
                        val resolvable = exception as ResolvableApiException
                        // Start resolution for result
                        locationSettingsLauncher.launch(resolvable.resolution)
                        //resolvable.startResolutionForResult(activity, LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST)
                    } else {
                        // Handle other types of exceptions (e.g., network issues, internal errors)
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Location settings could not be resolved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
                    // Catch any potential casting issues (though unlikely)
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
}

// Register for location settings resolution result
val locationSettingsLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { result ->
    // Handle result after location settings resolution
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        locationViewModel.requestLocationUpdates()
        // Location settings are now enabled, proceed with location updates
        Toast.makeText(context, "Location settings enabled. Proceeding with location updates.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        // Continue with your location request logic
    } else {
        locationViewModel.removeLocationUpdates()
        // User canceled or didn't enable location settings
        Toast.makeText(context, "Location settings are required.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}


I found on my way, It is working, but it is right way i don't know!!!

    val activity = context.findActivity() as ComponentActivity

    // Registering the result launcher for intent sender resolution
    val resolutionLauncher = remember {
        activity.activityResultRegistry.register("resolutionLauncher", ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                locationViewModel.requestLocationUpdates()
            } else {
                locationViewModel.removeLocationUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
    

And i need to use this launcher to send resolution pending intent,
  resolutionLauncher.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(
                            resolvable.resolution.intentSender).build())

